# Datatable with bootstrap modal window

Tags: datatable, modal-dialog

I have two pages...both are having same table content...the only difference is in their content loading technique..

1) http://myraipur.com/SuprError/Test2.php
Here the datatable content is loaded by simple “Tr” and “Td”. Modal window is working properly.

2) http://myraipur.com/SuprError/Test1.php
Here the datatable content is loaded via deferred loading. The modal window is not working.

can you please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run this code when your deferred is finished instead of document ready:

```
$("a[data-toggle=modal]").click(function (e) {
    lv_target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    lv_url = $(this).attr('href');
    $(lv_target).load(lv_url);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a method I feel that is straight forward that worked for me. ( Also my first Stackoverflow post! )

First used the Javascript Modal function provided by, 
http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/05/creating-simple-please-wait-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap

```js
 var loading;
 loading = loading || (function () {
  var pleaseWaitDiv = $('<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog modal-sm"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><h4 class="modal-title" id="mySmallModalLabel">Loading Data</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%"></div></div></div></div><!-- /.modal-content --></div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->');
  return {
   showPleaseWait: function() {
    pleaseWaitDiv.modal();
   },
   hidePleaseWait: function () {
    pleaseWaitDiv.modal('hide');
   },

  };
 })();
```

And here is my Data table call

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#address')
    .on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ) {
        if (processing) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#address').click(loading.showPleaseWait());
   });
  } else {
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#address').click(loading.hidePleaseWait());
   });  
  
  
  }
    } )
    .dataTable({
                 "Processing": false,
                 "sAjaxSource": "ajax/ajax_address_list.php",
                 "aoColumns": [
                        { mData: 'add_cust' } ,
                        { mData: 'add_main' },
                        { mData: 'add_alias' }
                ],
    "iDisplayLength": 50

        });  
 } );
```

Hope this helps!